# Removing basic header/text elements from a theme

Tags: themes

[image]

I couldn't figure this out myself so I figured I'd post this here. I'm building a site with Elementor on wordpress. I am using the standard theme of 2021 wordpress. But how do I get rid of the huge text?

Comment: You would need to find where it is in your themes code and remove it, this isn't something that can be answered by looking at a screenshot, and themes aren't all built the same way so there is no generic answer for all people. Have you contacted your themes support route?

Comment: This is literally the standard wordpress theme tom. I would have clarified if it wasn't.

Comment: Do you have a link? It's almost impossible to help with only a screenshot and a word based description. Have you modified the theme? If so how?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem and could not. What you have in your screenshot is not normal twentytwentyone styling or layout, the default theme puts the sites logo on top of not to the side of the menu when the title/tagline is shown. You also have 3rd party plugins installed, have you confirmed they are not the cause by turning all of them off to test? Have you used a child theme or custom CSS?

Answer (score 0):

inspect the page, get the class and put on css

```css
.theClass{
    display:none;
}
```

also if you want to remove the text on the header, probably will be on the file header.php

this are maybe the two ways I would do it, there are many more.